# Upgrade Apache Superset 1.4.1 to the latest (2.0?)

Tags: upgrade, apache-superset

how to upgrade Apache Superset 1.4.1 to the latest (2.0),i want to use the version 2.0.how to migrate database,update database etc?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the following to upgrade

```
pip install apache-superset --upgrade
```

However, you may face some dependency problems,as mentioned in this [issue](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/19767). This is about the wrong dependencies being fetched.
To sort it out, use the following (from the issue itself)

```
pip install Werkzeug==2.0.3
pip install flask==2.0.3
pip install jinja2==3.0.1
```

Then run the superset database [upgrade](https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/upgrading-superset/)

```
superset db upgrade
```